# Android: Orientation Change Based On Screen Size

Tags: java, android, screen, orientation

I need certain activities of mine to only change to landscape if the screen is big enough.

This means tablets and phones with screen size 5.1in+.

Is there anyway to do this through overriding onConfigurationChanged(...) and using the XML statement:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Comment: I think you can use your own "namespace" even for your Manifest.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can.  You can sniff for the screen size and using an if statement if binary or a switch otherwise to set the orientation of the view manually:

```
Display d = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();         
screenWidth = (int)(d.getWidth());
screenHeight = (int)(d.getHeight());

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: Doesn't Display.getWidth()/getHeight() return size in pixels?

Comment: fair enough:

      DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();

Comment: mainContext.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm)

Comment: Which override function I will add this code block?