# GridView's "Num colunms" change with screen resolution

Tags: android, gridview

I use a GridView to show list of pictures.
I want to set the num columns change with screen resolution.
Such as below:
If screen width > 512, then set num columns to 5.
Else if screen width > 256, then set num columns to 3.
Else, then set num columns to 2.
How to arrive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two views and inflate the desired one based on screen resolution.  See this SO solution as reference:

[Android: Orientation Change Based On Screen Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320559/android-orientation-change-based-on-screen-size/9320604#9320604)